# Reject call number in Android

Tags: android, telephony, phone-call

I want to write some code in Android that can detect phone number and state.

So when a specific number is calling (let's say 123456789), the app rejects that number and ends the call. What should I do?

```
public class ReciveCalls extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public  void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){
            String state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String Number=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(context,"Number:"+Number+",state:"+state,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT,3,0);
            toast.show();
        }
      }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get AudioManager
    this.context = context;
    // Get TelephonyManager
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // Get incoming number
            incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            if(incomingNumber) //check the number and reject the call
            {
                    rejectCall();
            }


        }
    }


}
```

And reject call by using below method:

```
 private void rejectCall() {
    try {

        // Get the getITelephony() method
        Class<?> classTelephony = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
        Method method = classTelephony.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        // Disable access check
        method.setAccessible(true);
        // Invoke getITelephony() to get the ITelephony interface
        Object telephonyInterface = method.invoke(telephonyManager);
        // Get the endCall method from ITelephony
        Class<?> telephonyInterfaceClass = Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());
        Method methodEndCall = telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");
        // Invoke endCall()
        methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```